# The idea of the proof of theorem 2.1 in Stein and Shakarchi' Fourier Analysis book

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

The Book States the following Theorem:

Suppose that $f$ is an integrable function on the circle with $\hat{f}(n) = 0$ for all $n\in  \mathbb{Z}.$ Then $f(\theta_{o})=0$ whenever $f$ is continuous at the point $\theta_{o}$.

I do not understand exactly why he choose $\delta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ and why this leads to $f(\theta) > \frac{f(0)}{2}$ and what is the importance of that  $f(\theta) > \frac{f(0)}{2}$?Also why he choose the trigonometric polynomial in that way and what is the importance of choosing $\eta < \delta$, so that $p(\theta) \geq 1 + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$? why he let $p_{k}(\theta) = [p(\theta)]^{k}$ in part $2$ and $3$ of the proof. Could anyone explain this for me please?$

[image: the theorem]
[image: the proof part 1]
[image: the proof part 2]
[image: the proof part 3]

Comment: By the way this result is an immediate corollary to Fejér's theorem which says, in particular, that if $f$ is an integrable function on the circle then $\sigma_n f(\theta) \to f(\theta)$ at each $\theta$ where $f$ is continuous. Hence if $\hat{f}(n) = 0$ for all $n \in \Bbb{Z}$ and if $f$ is continuous at $\theta_0$, then $\sigma_n f(\theta_0) \equiv 0 \to 0 = f(\theta_0)$.

Comment: at this level of the book it did not give Fejer theorem @NeedForHelp

Comment: Related question:
[Theorem 2.1 in Stein and Shakarachi the complex valued function case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2182070/theorem-2-1-in-stein-and-shakarachi-the-complex-valued-function-case.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do not understand exactly why he choose $\delta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ and why this leads to $f(θ) > \frac{f(0)}{2}$ and what is the importance of that $f(θ) > \frac{f(0)}{2}$ ?

They choose $\delta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ to make sure that $p(\theta)$ is non-negative whenever $|\theta|<\delta$.

All they want is a neighborhood of $0$ on which $f>0$. The value $\frac{f(0)}{2}$ is just a simple choice.

That they can choose such a $\delta$ is a consequence of the continuity of $f$ at $0$ :
$$
\exists\, \delta > 0, \forall\, \theta : |\theta| < \delta \implies f(0)-\frac{f(0)}{2} =\frac{f(0)}{2} < f(\theta)
$$

> Also why he choose the trigonometric polynomial in that way and what is the importance of choosing $\eta < \delta$, so that $p(\theta) \geq 1 + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ ?

They would like to choose $p$ such that $p>1$ on $(-\delta,\delta)$. But that's impossible because $p$ is continuous and they chose $\epsilon$ such that $|p(\theta)| < 1$ whenever $\delta \leq \theta \leq \pi$. That's why they need to restrict to $(-\eta,\eta) \subset (-\delta,\delta)$.

The value $1+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ is unimportant as long as it is $> 1$. They could not simply choose $1+\epsilon$ because $p(0) = 1+\epsilon$.

> why he let $p_k(\theta) = [p(\theta)]^k$

They saw that for any trigonometric polynomial $p$, $p^k$ is also a trigonometric polynomial. So they really started with $p_k := p^k$ in mind and chose $p$ so that $p^k$ peaks at $0$. To do so they used the fact that $a^k$ tends to $\infty$ if $a > 1$ and to $0$ if $|a| < 1$.

> Could anyone explain this for me please?

While the proof is a bit technical, the idea is simple enough:

1. If $f(0) > 0$ then by continuity of $f$ at $0$ there is a *neighborhood* of $0$ on which $f > 0$.
2. Then if $p_k$ peak at $0$ we *should* have
   $$
   \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} p_k(\theta) f(\theta) \,d\theta \to \infty \tag{$\star$}
   $$

In the proof they take care of the details on how to construct $p_k$ precisely and how to show rigorously $(\star)$ happens.