# Proving a theorem related to uniqueness of Fourier Series for complex-valued function.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, complex-integration

I was studying **Fourier Analysis: An Introduction** by *Stein and Shakarchi*.

I came across this theorem in Section 2.2, page number 39

> **Theorem 2.1** Suppose that $f$ is an integrable function on the circle with $\hat f(n) = 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then $f(\theta_0) = 0$ whenever f is continuous at the point $\theta_0$.

This was first proved for real-valued functions, which I understood. Then the proof was extended to complex-valued functions, with a brief explanation.

> In general, write $f(\theta) = u(\theta) + iv(\theta)$, where $u$ and $v$ are real-valued. If we define $\overline f(\theta) = \overline{f(\theta)}$, then $$u(\theta)=\dfrac{f(\theta)+\overline f(\theta)}{2}$$ and $$v(\theta)=\dfrac{f(\theta)-\overline f(\theta)}{2i}$$ and since $\hat{\overline{f}}(n) = \overline{\hat f(-n)}$, we conclude that the Fourier coefficients of $u$ and $v$ all vanish, hence $f = 0$ at its points of continuity.

I have a confusion in the last part. How does $\hat{\overline{f}}(n) = \overline{\hat f(-n)}$ lead us to conclude that $f=0$ at its points of continuity?

Comment: When you say "I don't understand what $\overline f(\theta)=\overline{f(\theta)}$ means", for $f(\theta)=u(\theta)+i\, v(\theta)$ where $u(\theta)$ and $v(\theta)$ are both real valued, isn't it just $\overline f(\theta)=\overline{f(\theta)}=u(\theta)-i\, v(\theta)$?

Comment: @StevenClark What I meant was, does the bar over only f and the bar over the whole expression mean the same thing? Or do they mean different things, which are equal in our case?

Comment: My interpretation of "If we define $\overline f(\theta) = \overline{f(\theta)}$" is that its a definition and therefore just an equivalent shorthand notation.

Comment: I found an answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2182223/1055581